# User-compiled version of `pal` behaves differently than the binary distribution?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I am running `pal 0.4.3` on `Ubuntu 13.10`.

In the version that lives in `/usr/bin/pal` after doing `sudo apt-get install pal`, running `pal -m` results in the normal calendar being displayed with some detailed fields.

If I instead do `apt-get source pal`, and build the downloaded package using `make` with no arguments, and then run `./pal -m`, my terminal background changes to gray while `pal` is running, and then reverts to the original black after program termination.

What might account for the difference? More generally, is it possible to query the binary package to figure out what options it was compiled with, and with which compiler?

The output from `pal --version` and `./pal --version` is identical:

```
pal 0.4.3
Compiled with prefix: /usr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the Ubuntu package made some modifications to the source before compiling it.

The gray background goes away if I build with the following sequence of commands:

```
apt-get source pal
make -f debian/rules
make
```